# Why is RGB code for green such a mess?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Logically, green should be #00FF00 because green is G in RGB where R is #FF0000 and B is #0000FF

However, all the RGB tables list green as #008000 while #00FF00 is actually lime. I played with a browser by setting background color using names and codes and clearly green=#008000 and lime=#00FF00

Some sources provide the codes incorrectly, e.g.
Wikipedia says green is  #00FF00    at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green

It also says lime is  #BFFF00   at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lime_(color)

NOTE: many responders seem to confuse RGB code with RGB format. The same RGB code can have several formats like the same number can have several different formats, e.g. you can represent the decimal 10 in decimal, binary, octal, hex, etc. Equivalently the same RGB code can be represented in the functional notation rgb(R,G,B), or hex notation using 6 or 3 hex digits. So #00FF00 is the same as rgb(0,255,0). This topic has nothing to do with the question.

The question asks about consistency. Even anybody with elementary education would notice immediately the lack of consistency when assigning code #008000 when #00FF00 is the obvious choice. Since this is such a huge eyesore in basic logic then I would assume that many sources would explain the reason for choosing #008000. The lack of explanation itself is the most surprising. No professional would pass it up.

Comment: First off, you mention RGB but you are showing Hex codes. Green in RGB is (0,128,0). What you should be asking is "Why are red and blue both 255 in RGB, while green is 128." Also your second link is broken.

Comment: I don't know anyone who uses pre-selected CSS colors in their final project...  Not sure why it's such a concern.  But as a designer, when I want "green" I don't want 00FF00 because that truely is a lime green.  The fact that the highest value of the green spectrum on a pixel is bright green is just what helps all of the other millions of colors look the they way they do.  Without it being that high of a color, the other colors would be muddy.  Also remember, the Wiki article was written by "someone" - Not "someone from W3C"

Comment: @AndyM: Hexadecimal codes aren't a seperate color system, just a seperate denotation for RGB colors.

Comment: And at the original questioner: Since you edited your question after I posted my answer that I feel does answer what you're asking still, could you comment on said answer with what's missing so that I can edit it accordingly?

Comment: @TheThirdMan, Hex codes are a way to write out a combination of red, green, and blue, it's true. In recent years though, colloquial usage has come down to "Hex" or "RGB"  with "RGB" referring to `rgb(0-255,0-255,0-255)`. I guess technically, it's RGB Hex, and RGB Decimal, but if you walk up to most web devs and start talking about RGB codes, the assumption is going to be rgb().

Comment: @AndyM: I see that point and I've never argued on that matter, however that part is irrelevant to the question at hand. You and others have implied that Hex codes are not accurate representations of RGB values, which is strictly wrong. The questioner clearly wasn't asking about the syntax of the rgb() function whatsoever, but about the RGB color scheme.

Comment: Eh, fair enough. Interesting discussion, but not really relevant to the OP. In a minute I'll delete both of my comments here to reduce the clutter.

Answer (score 5):

The RGB tables you're talking about must be lists of the named colors for use in HTML and CSS (of which you can find a list [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/named-colors-and-hex-equivalents/)), which are named after what you would instinctively name the color, being used to non-light colors as they are used in print. However expressing those values in RGB (additive light colors) is done in ranges of 0 to 255 for three values named red, green and blue. Those names have nothing to do with the HTML/CSS named colors, and this is simply why they don't match (plus naming the spectrum red-lime-blue would be weird).

According to the table above, these are your HTML/CSS values that the names will be replaced with:

- green: #008000
- lime: #00FF00

The RGB spectrum is based on their name-giving base colors, which mix to other colors accordingly, as you can see in the next graphic. As you can imagine, if you would use the CSS-green in place of the one RGB is actually using, the inbetween colors would equally change their appearance, and the whole model wouldn't be all that useable.

[image: RGB spectrum]
([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:AdditiveColor.svg))

On that note, the Wikipedia entry you linked is correct on their color attribution, as it's the "true" value of green within the RGB spectrum. The HTML/CSS colors however are named by their more instinctive interpretation, likely because that's what you would think of first.

---

Furthermore, there is an [article about the history of named colors](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/10/tomato-versus-ff6347-the-tragicomic-history-of-css-color-names/) that, while not having any relevant mention of this particular color, further underlines my analysis of it being done for purposes that suit the eye of the average user, not that of the average screen engineer. To quote it:

*Still, the general consensus is that these colors’ utility is minimal; they’re best reserved as placeholders (it’s easier to type “tomato” than “#FF6347” when you need a color quickly), for beginner-level design projects, or as the butt of a joke.*

Answer (score 1):

Ok first  off, ... you are mentioning Hex colors. the rgb color syntax is as:

`rgb(255,0,0)` (for red). *Hex colors aren't a separate system of colors, its just a different way of mentioning, but what you are asking may reduce clarity.*

Now, to your question. The reason that green is not 255 but is instead 128 is because the purpose of rgb is not just too create 1 single special color, but mix with other color codes to create more colors. The lighter green hue is made to better mix with other colors to create colors that better utilize the other values.

Comment: Hexadecimal codes aren't a seperate color system, just a seperate denotation for RGB colors and perfectly fine at that. In it's history, hexadecimal codes came decades before the rgb(r, g, b) notation.